# Detecting updated container images or Helm charts of my Kubernetes deployments

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Is there a way to detect updates for container images that have been deployed in my Kubernetes cluster? The deployment has been made by installing a Helm chart. So I thought that Helm would provide a way to detect if an installed chart has available updates. But I can't seem to find any.

What I'm basically looking for is the Helm (or equivalent) version of `apt list --upgradable`.

**Additional information about my use-case:**

I'm running a Kubernetes cluster in Azure which I want to integrate with Azure's logging system (OMS). This is done by deploying the `microsoft/oms` container image with the `stable/msoms` Helm chart.

The `microsoft/oms` container image is regularly updated with new features or bug fixes. I want an easy way to view if I run the latest version or if there are updates available. Of course I can check manually with `kubectl describe deployment %name%` and compare the image version with the latest version on Docker Hub, but that's pretty tedious and doesn't scale well.

Comment: Great use case for a little in-cluster container that checks what's running against what's available, perhaps in conjunction with a metadata service like grafeas: https://grafeas.io/. I am not personally aware of such a tool at this point, would be fun to produce.

Comment: This (useful) capability should be under the responsibility of the Helm repository, which currently doesn't cover this. The ChartMuseum open source project is trying to innovate beyond the standard and minimal Helm spec, for example: https://github.com/kubernetes-helm/chartmuseum/issues/83 but it's not there yet. Watch out for this in the future